# Selects dependientes en 3 niveles en Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Estoy intentando realizar selects dependientes en 3 niveles, sin acceso a base de datos.

¿Cómo podría hacerlos en Angular JS?

**Ejemplo:**

Paises >

- Departamentos >

  - Provincias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto debes hacer algo asi :

Defines los 3 selectores

```
<select name="selectPais" id="selectPais" ng-model="data.defaultPais" ng-options="pais.paisCodigo as pais.paisNombre for pais in paises track by pais.paisCodigo" ng-change="updateDropDownDepartamentos(data.defaultPais)">
    <option value="">Seleccione país</option>
</select>

<select name="selectDepartamento" id="selectDepartamento" ng-disabled="!data.defaultPais" ng-model="data.defaultDepartamento" ng-options="departamento.deptoId as departamento.deptoNombre for departamento in departamentos_filter " ng-change="updateDropDownProvincias(data.defaultDepartamento)">
    <option value="">Seleccione departamento</option>
</select>


<select name="selectProvincias" id="selectProvincias" ng-model="data.defaultProvincias" ng-options="provincia.proNombre for provincia in provincias_filter">
    <option value="">Seleccione categoría</option>
</select>
```

Como te puedes dar cuenta en el primer select le das las opciones de tu arreglo de paises o tu lista, cada pais DEBERIA tener un codigo (`pais.paisCodigo` en este ejemplo) defines un ng-model que es `data.defaultPais`. Cuando este selector cambia llama a la funcion `updateDropDownDepartamentos` que recibe como parametro el pais que selecciono.

```
$scope.updateTheOtherDropdown = function(pais) {
    $scope.departamentos_filter = $filter('filter')($scope.departamentos, { deptoPaisCodigo: pais });
}
```

En esta funcion, dentro de tu arreglo de Departamentos, filtrar por los que solo tienen el `deptoPaisCodigo` que seleccionaste en el primer selector y declaras la variable $scope.departamentos_filter que ocupas para llenar el segundo selector. Esto en el tercer selector ocurre de la misma forma.

Te dejo un codepen para que lo entiendas mejor [Codepen Select](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/WoJBqr)

Comment: Muchas gracias sioesi, una última consulta, contarás con un ejemplo de como puedo intregarlo con php (pdo), te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Si quieres te puedo ayudar con php, pero deja mas o menos tus tablas y tus querys pero saber mas o menos como es